# Flash on Ubuntu 16.04 NEVER works on ANY browser

Tags: internet, internet-radio

Flash on Ubuntu 16.04 never works on any browser;
i.e.; chrome, chromium, and firefox. <<< updated, plugins enabled and updated, contents/privacy setting properly checked.
dns pointing same as my windows pc, which plays flash on internet radios;
i.e.; bbc.co.uk, tsf jazz, nhk online <<< none plays on ubuntu.
What else to do? Now I can never listen to any internet radio.

Comment: Did you actually install Flash? Chrome's been phasing out support for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I blacklisted the `flashplugin-installer` package on all my computers and uninstalled it because it's a very old version and I don't want that in Firefox. However I have pepperflashplugin-nonfree in Chromium which plays http://www.tsfjazz.com/player.html just fine, Chrome should also be fine.

Since you didn't provide any further details (I couldn't find the other examples you mentioned nor did you provide error messages or how it looks on your end) I cannot help you any further.

[image]

Comment: It's been a couple of days and I still can't listen to bbc.co.uk/radio3.  Let's try to present my situation as simple as can be.

Comment: Please try and access this site and see what happens; http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio3/  and for argument's sake, lets keep it on "Firefox"  If you right click on anywhere vacant on the webpage, you see "Inspect Element" on Firefox.  Click on "Network" tab and you see what's going on.

Comment: On ther other hand, I leant since that I can access npr.org and play internet radio.  They seem to push their own thing.  I think Ubuntu is largely developed in U.S., so BBC is ignored.  Let us litsen to BBC.CO.UK.  If you are Americans, UK music is a fun thing to listen to - aside their accents.

Comment: Oh, I can play TSF Jazz on Firefox.  Will you try bbc.co.uk/radio3 ? on Firefox as will and see the right-click "Inspect Element" and "Network" tab, and tell me what you think.

Comment:  ' . Anyways, I just tried BBC in a VM updating Flash and Firefox to the most recent version, no problems here, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: ![valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8-KkrPCMWJaNkVDMzF4STJ2anc).

Comment: <https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8-KkrPCMWJaNkVDMzF4STJ2anc>

Comment: On the link is my screenshot.  You see the "network" result.  Can you figure out?  Mine set up is same as yours.

Comment: Initiater:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_three

lib.js:7 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: bump-3
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeoutmakeError @ lib.js:7L @ lib.js:7(anonymous function) @ lib.js:7
http://emp.bbci.co.uk/emp/bump-3/bump-3.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET  <<<<<
lib.js:7 Uncaught Error: Script error for: bump-3
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterrormakeError @ lib.js:7onScriptError @ lib.js:7

Comment: since then, I did this;      root@Latitude-E6500:/opt/strobe# ls
StrobeMediaPlayback_1.6.328-full    but still Firefox do not play bbc.co.uk/radio3

Comment: Sorry, there is some slight misunderstanding here. Your question got close voted as a duplicate because it looked like you had minor problems with installing flash correctly and make it work. Comments are not quite fit for problem investigation, I recommend to edit your question and add all the new information, so other users of this site can see the current status/problem unlock your question for further answers and hopefully find a solution. So please edit your question, let me know via a comment so I can vote to reopen your question.

Comment: Well, I'm unable to edit my original question.  What is ''1.17.0.1770359-SMPFlash'' which shows on the mid-left of your screen shot?

Comment: As you see on my screen shot, I have no f4f or mp4 file transaction on the ''Inspect Element'' "Network" tab.  Could this be due to some .so file missing on lib?  I did not do this when I installed flash player.